# javascript runtime error

Tags: javascript

I am using a ckeditor in replacement with a textbox id txtEditorAnswer but on running I found the following error in these lines

```
x.tabIndex=x.config.tabIndex||x.element.getAttribute('tabindex')||0;

o.modes={wysiwyg:!!n.element.$.form};

if(x.elementMode==1&&y.is('textarea'))

var z=y.$.form&&new h(y.$.form);
```

Comment: and on which of those lines does it occur?

Comment: the error is jscript runtime error and it is in all these lines when I used a debugger..

Comment: jscript runtime error object required. is the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first line, I would guess that one of `x`, `x.config`, `x.element` or `x.element.getAttribute`, are undefined.

The other lines would follow a similar pattern.  i.e. an object whose members you are trying to access, does not exist, or a function you are trying to call, does not exist.

As you are using a debugger, you should be able to inspect the variables to verify this.